# How to reduce object detection time on a model trained over ResNet?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, resnet, torchvision

I have an custom object detection model trained over ResNet50 using PyTorch. It takes ~300ms to provide detection result after passing the image through the model.

Is there any way to reduce the detection time?

Answer (score 0):

300ms with ResNet50 is not so bad. It looks like you managed to run it on a GPU. When I looked at it the last time, it did not work on GPU on iOS or even Linux.

Three things to check and experiment with:

1. Image resolution.
2. Anchors allocation.
3. Number of layers. For some tasks, resnet18 performs only slightly worse than resnet50.